# startnet.cmd issues when silently installing Windows 7

Tags: windows

I am trying to start windows 7 unattended using the startnet.cmd file. The problem is that when the start setup.exe command is triggered, the setup runs and closes, but cannot reboot because the startnet.cmd is still open. If I put "exit", it starts the setup and exits immediately. Is there a way to check uf the setup ran successfully and then perform an exit?

```
wpeinit
net use u: \\192.168.2.10\windows
u:
start setup.exe /unattend:\\192.168.2.10\windows\unattend.xml /noreboot
REM ping -n 30 127.0.0.1
REM exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your commands are correct but you explicitly state that `setup.exe` shall not initiate a reboot after the first phase of the setup procedure has completed.

The black `cmd.exe` Window will have to remain open during the setup procedure. If it's terminated then Windows PE performs an immediate reboot. Hence your setup.exe process will be terminated. I think your comment using ping to delay the exit very well shows that you have tried to delay terminating the shell process. But as you can't know how long the setup process will take you cannot fill any good value in the delay algorithm.

Although I think you don't need to. You are launching `setup.exe` using  `start` which detaches the process and returns to the shell immediately. In fact since setup.exe is the last command you run you could also live with the fact that setup.exe is not detached. Either by not using `start` or by using `start /wait`

```
wpeinit
net use u: \\192.168.2.10\windows
u:
setup.exe /unattend:\\192.168.2.10\windows\unattend.xml /noreboot
exit
```

or

```
wpeinit
net use u: \\192.168.2.10\windows
u:
start /wait setup.exe /unattend:\\192.168.2.10\windows\unattend.xml /noreboot
exit
```

Although I think the entire purpose of this would be to return to the shell and perform the `exit` (which initiates a reboot) command after `setup.exe` terminates.

As there are no more commands to be executed I suggest letting `setup.exe` do the reboot itself by removing the `/noreboot` flag:

```
wpeinit
net use u: \\192.168.2.10\windows
u:
start setup.exe /unattend:\\192.168.2.10\windows\unattend.xml
```

This should keep the shell process (`cmd.exe`) open while setup is running. At the end of the setup process it will initiate a reboot (initiated by `setup.exe`) and therefore also te